# Modern advanced problem book in Differential Equations and/or Calculus of Variations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

Please tell me that are known modern advanced problem books in Differential Equations and/or Calculus of Variations?

I am interested in books like

Biler Nadzieja "Problems and Examples in Differential Equations",

not in introductory books. I strongly prefer problem books over texts, but if there are texts with a lot of theoretical problems, please let me know about them.

Thanks a lot for your time.